# j2me sms receive works in emulator but does not work in nokia n91?

Tags: java, java-me, sms

I have made j2me SMS receive app.when i tried in in sun WTK it works
fine. It receives SMS in the emulator, but when I tried in Nokia n91, it does not receive it.

Comment: can you please post some code .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the default sms inbox (port 0 of the sms protocol), you just can't do it with the usual virtual machine. The most you can do is to listen to a specific port and receive sms's sent to that port. If you want to do that, then the messages you send have to be specifically destined to that custom port.

[Here it's a topic](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?151379-How-to-read-SMS-from-inbox-in-j2me) "discussing" this at the Nokia forum.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks in advance..., but i have listen to the specific port eg.5001 to listern the sms it works when i send sms through emulator to my app in port 5001 but when in real device it doesnot work.Also i have use same port to send sms.please help me.Its important

Comment: @user609360 Maybe you could add some code to your message, otherwise is pretty hard to solve it. But I can tell you, all Nokia devices I tried have such capacity.